# flask app with subdomain on openshift

Tags: subdomain, flask, openshift

I created python flask app, and deployed to openshift. It can be accessed at

```
https://ledgerware-hj.rhcloud.com
```

Now I'd like to use subdomain names for language code. On my local pc I added the following line to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 ledgerware.dev
127.0.0.1 en.ledgerware.dev
```

I also configured flask app:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'ledgerware.dev:5000'
```

Everything works if I browse to http://en.ledgerware.dev:5000.
For openshift I configured flask app to be:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'ledgerware-hj.rhcloud.com'
```

But, https://en.ledgerware-hj.rhcloud.com won't work, because there must be other settings to be done. What else should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog related to your issue that has some suggestions: 
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way

Can you please take a look at it and see if it helps?